# Tree evaluation with operators

Tags: c#, tree

I try to evaluate a tree with some conditional operators AND or OR at each Nodes.

How can I do it to navigate the tree and apply the conditions.

[image: Tree to evaluate with conditional operators]

My code is:

```
 public class EvaluationGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EvaluationGroupOperator Operator { get; set; }

    public List<Criteria> Criterias { get; set; }

    public EvaluationGroup NextGroup { get; set; }
    public EvaluationGroup PrevGroup { get; set; }

    internal bool EvaluateTree()
    {
        bool isValidated = false;

        EvaluationGroup currentGroup = this;

        while (currentGroup != null)
        {
            if (Criterias == null)
            {
                isValidated = false;
                break;
            }

            foreach (var criterion in Criterias)
            {

            }

            currentGroup = currentGroup.NextGroup;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean to evaluate a group, since it doesn't return anything?

Comment: side note: singular for "criteria", which is plural, is "criterion". Hence `foreach (var criterion in Criteria)`

Comment: Can you declare type EvaluationGroup and use it inside of itself? Or what’s  the data looks like. Consider filtering with Linq.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Criteria is not a tree structure.  A Tree has Nodes with values.  You can apply a criteria to the value.  You can pick children with value less than 100 but what does "AND" mean against a child node?

Comment: Ok. I am going to be clearer. The evaluation group at level 1 (criteria 2, 3, 4), must return true. Then the Criteria2 && Criteria 3 && Criteria 4 = true. If it is an OR operator it should satisfy: Criteria2 || Criteria 3 || Criteria 4 = true. And then I have to evaluate criteria 5, 6 and 7 for the criteria 4.